# Finding second order partial derivatives of implicitly defined $g(a, b)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

I have an implicitly defined $C^1$ function $z=g(x, y)$ as a solution of $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ to $G(x, y, z)=0$ of some $C^1$ function $G$.

Then I have the derivative of $g$ 
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial (x, y)}(a, b)+\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(a, b)\cdot Dg(a, b)=0$$

I'm wondering how to get the second order partial derivatives $D_1D_2g, D_1D_1g, D_2D_2g, D_2D_1g$ from this.

Answer (score 0):

something like this $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial (x, y)}(a, b)\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(a, b)\cdot Dg(a, b)\right)=0$$ and then use chain rule, similarly in second direction